# LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to bitbucket.org:443

Tags: git, curl, bitbucket

starting last 2-3 weeks I can not open bitbucket.org, from anywhere in my Mac OS 10.13.4 and from Windows 7 using browser, curl and on "git push" I'm getting SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL. I tried to connect from another internet provider but got the same issue.

I don't have any proxies set and etc.

Curl log here:

[image]

Please help

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect bitbucket.org:443
```

gives following output

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like the TCP handshake succeeds, but that the connection is being interrupted someplace during the TLS handshake. What's the output of `echo | openssl s_client -connect bitbucket.org:443` on one of the affected systems?

Comment: @JimRedmond I've added output from terminal to the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

my country government blocked BigBucket IPs.

> The Ministry of Information and Communications of Kazakhstan, has blocked Bitbucket IPs.
>   To get this resolved you will need to work with your local ISP.
>   As a workaround, you can configure a Proxy to route through a different provider or use VPN connection to access Bitbucket from a different network.

Comment: currently BitBucket is reachable without vpn/proxy

Answer (score 0):

It comes due to IP6 in Mac's wi-fi/ hotspot. So, whenever you'll get IP4 it'll work. So the solution is :
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
and then
git push
Hope it'll work

Answer (score 0):

I was connected to my organisation's network over the VPN and was able to connect organisation's private bitbucket repo. When I came back after 2 weeks leave and tried cloning a repo I got the following error.
[image: error screen shot]

I tried everything mentioned on different forums but nothing worked, only thing which resolved this issue was that I connected to a different Wifi network. As soon as I connected to a different network everything started working as normal.

Answer (score -2):

networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi

run this in your terminial
the issue is with your wifi